# Dúvida lista encadeada usando JS/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou novamente estudando estruturas de dados e resolvi usar como base um livro de estrutura de dados usado JavaScript. O código inicial de linkedList.js está assim:

```
import {defaultEquals} from '../util/util.js';
import { Node } from './models/linked-list-models.js';

export default class linkedList{
//Aqui ficara o construtor...
constructor(equalsFn = defaultEquals){
    this.count = 0;
    this.head = undefined;
    this.equalsFn = equalsFn;
}

//Aqui comecam os metodos...
push(element){
    const node = new Node(element);
    let current;        

    console.log(this.head);
    if (this.head == null){                     
        this.head = node;
        
    }
    else{            
        current = this.head;
        while(current.next != null){                
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = node;
    }
    this.count++;              
    }    
}

let a = new linkedList();
a.push(1);
a.push(2);
a.push(3);
a.push(4);
```

E o código da classe linked-list-models.js a qual é usada pelo método push está assim:

```
export class Node {
constructor(element){
    this.element = element;
    this.next = undefined;
    }
}
```

E o código de util.js (não usando no momento) está assim:

```
export function defaultEquals(a, b){
    return a === b; //exporta o valor de comparacao entre dois valores em um booleano
}
```

A minha dúvida é simples, pois nãop consigo entender como o atributo *this.head* é atualizado e como ele se torna uma lista encadeada, pois somente *node* e *current*/*current.next* são atualizados.

Agradeço a todos desde ja!

Answer (score -2):

No teu código, this.head só é alterada uma vez, que é onde tens:

```
if (this.head == null){                     
    this.head = node;
}
```

O que isso faz é verificar se a lista está vazia sabendo se `this.head == null`. Se a lista estiver vazia, o node que acabaste de criar passa a ser o primeiro elemento da lista ligada. O primeiro elemento é também a cabeça (head), daí o `this.head = node`.

A partir daí, qualquer novo elemento que seja adicionado à lista é colocado a seguir ao último, mas o `this.head` continua sempre a apontar para o primeiro, nunca mais é atualizado.

Para saberes qualquer é o último node, tens de percorrer a lista desde o início até ao fim. Para isso, utilizas a variável auxiliar `current` que começas por apontar para o início da lista com `current = this.head` e depois vais percorrendo os vários nodes até encontrar o último e aí adicionas o novo elemento.